# .NET email interception

Tags: .net, email

Are there any good frameworks or libraries that allow a .NET application to read emails from an Exchange mailbox, parse them for data like sender, recipient, subject, and body, and mark them as processed on Exchange (mark as read, delete, etc)?

Comment: If you have Outlook you can write a plugin to Outlook.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Reviewing options...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this:

http://exchangenotification.codeplex.com/

Basically you get an event when a mail arrives and then you can process it. It works together with [Exchange Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877045.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Any IMAP or POP3 implementation would do.

- http://imapnet.codeplex.com/
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/imaplibrary.aspx
- http://www.rebex.net/mail.net/

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just use [Exchange Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877045.aspx) (EWS)